# Center text (vertically/horizontally) with tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I created a little card, which should have a number on the left side. I solved this - but there is one little thing I could not solve until now.

This number should be horizontally and vertically centered.

This is what I did: https://codepen.io/spqrinc/pen/jOEraJx

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
<div class="md:flex lg:w-1/2 p-2">
  <div class="md:flex-1 rounded-sm shadow-lg text-gray-600 bg-white rounded-sm shadow-lg">
    <div class="overflow-hidden w-full flex leading-normal lg:h-full">
      <div class="sm:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 bg-teal-600 block">
        <div class="text-center text-6xl font-bold text-white">1</div>
      </div>
      <p class="text-gray-600  sm:w-2/3 lg:w-3/4 p-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, [content-center](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/align-content/) did not work out for me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/1.1.2/tailwind.min.css">
<div class="md:flex lg:w-1/2 p-2">
  <div class="md:flex-1 rounded-sm shadow-lg text-gray-600 bg-white rounded-sm shadow-lg">
    <div class="overflow-hidden w-full flex leading-normal lg:h-full">
      <div class="sm:w-1/3 lg:w-1/4 bg-teal-600 flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="text-center text-6xl font-bold text-white">1</div>
      </div>
      <p class="text-gray-600  sm:w-2/3 lg:w-3/4 p-4">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
        sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et
        ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The important part is the `flex items-center justify-center` instead of `block` in the fourth div.